# varnish vs squid? caching solution

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy

squid : Optimising Web Delivery - http://www.squid-cache.org/

Varnish : http://varnish-cache.org/

which one is better to use and why?

Comment: Better for what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is: it depends :)

Based in my experience with caching static content, Varnish is much faster when you have few concurrent connections but loses to squid when you have many concurrent connections, but this is only true for the work loads I've tested with my specific data.

There are many variables at stake. The best thing you can do is benchmarking both varnish and squid against your content and in your environment and then choose the one that best suits your needs.